# Prove that if the equations $x^2+bx+ca=0$ and $x^2+cx+ab=0$ have a common root,

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quadratics

Prove that if the equations $x^2+bx+ca=0$ and $x^2+cx+ab=0$ have a common root, their other roots will satisfy $x^2+ax+bc=0$.

My Attempt:

Given,
$$x^2+bx+ca=0$$
$$x^2+cx+ab=0$$
Let $\alpha $ be the common root of both our equations. So,
$$\alpha^2 + b\alpha + ca=0$$
$$\alpha^2 + c\alpha +ab=0.$$
If one root is common, then
$$(c-b)(ab^2-ac^2)=(ac-ab)^2.$$

Comment: never thought of setting the first two equal to each other ?

Comment: The common root of the given two equations is $a$. If $a\neq 0$, the other roots of the given equations are $c$ and $b$ respectively which obviously satisfy $x^2+ax+bc=0$.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas, Could you please elaborate? I didn't get anything..

Comment: First, $a,b,c$ must be pairwise distinct and this should have been clearly stated (otherwise the claim is obviously false).  Second, the condition $a\neq 0$ is missing.  If $a=0$ and $b+c\neq 0$, then the hypothesis holds but the claim is false.

Comment: @ Roddy MacPhee, Setting them equal, I got either $b=c$, or $\alpha =a$??

Comment: you get $x^2+bx+ca=x^2+cx+ab \implies bx+ca=cx+ab \implies (b-c)x=(b-c)a\implies a=x$ which has then been talked about by @PrasunBiswas

Comment: @blue_eyed_..., If $b\neq c$ and $\alpha=a\neq 0$, then the conclusion follows immediately by my previous comment. Now, what if $b=c$ or $a=0$ ?

Comment: It's trivial to note that if $b=c$, the two given equations are the same and all their roots are common and we can't proceed further without additional information. Now then, what if $a=0$ ?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas, The question clearly says, r
the equation has one root common, not both roots common!

Comment: @blue_eyed_..., Nope, the question **clearly** states that they have a root in common, not that they have **exactly one root** in common.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas, What does the letter (a) signify? one or two?

Comment: @blue_eyed_..., It says that they have one common root but it doesn't say anything about the other two roots. They might be common as well. Saying anything about the precedent doesn't imply anything about the subsequent.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments you will get that $a$ is the common root. Now you can use Vieta's formulas. Let  $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ the other root of the first and second equation, respectively. Then we have:

$$a\beta_1 = ca$$
$$a\beta_2 = ab$$

So $\beta_1 = c$ and $\beta_2 = b$. Now the rest shouldn't be too hard. In fact you get by Vieta's forumlas that $b + c = -\beta_1 - \beta_2 - 2a \iff -a = b+c$. Then we get that the quadratic polynomial that have $b$ and $c$ as roots is:

$$(x-b)(x-c) = x^2 - (b + c)x + bc = x^2 + ax + bc$$

Hence the proof.

Comment: How is $b+c=-\beta_1 - \beta_2 -2a$?

Comment: @blue_eyed_... Vieta's formula

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is wrong.

Try $b=c=6$ and $a=\frac{4}{3}$.

Given equations are $x^2+6x+8=0$, but the third equation $x^2+\frac{4}{3}x+36=0$ has no real roots.

Answer (score 0):

If $abc=0$,that's too trivial to need to discuss. We assume that $abc \neq 0$. Thus, all the roots do not equal $0.$

Let $\alpha, \beta $ be the roots for $x^2+bx+ca=0$. By Vieta's theorem,  we have $$\alpha+\beta=-b,\tag1$$$$\alpha\beta=ca.\tag 2$$

Similarily,let $\alpha, \gamma $ be the roots for $x^2+cx+ab=0$. By Vieta's theorem,  we have $$\alpha+\gamma=-c,\tag3$$$$\alpha\gamma=ab.\tag 4$$

Hence, by $(1)-(2)$, we have $$\beta-\gamma=-b+c.\tag5$$
By $(1) \div (2)$,we have $$\frac{\beta}{\gamma}=\frac{c}{b}. \tag6$$
From $(5)$ and $(6)$, we may obtain $$\beta=c,\tag7$$and$$\gamma=b.\tag8$$

Putting $(7)$ into $(2)$, we have $$\alpha=a.\tag9$$Putting $(7),(9)$ into $(1)$,we have $$a+c=-b.\tag{10}$$

Now, we may have $\beta+\gamma=c+b=c-(a+c)=-a,$and $\beta \gamma=bc.$ By Vieta's theorem, we may conclude that $\beta, \gamma$ are necessarily the roots for $x^2+a+bc=0.$ We are done!